# How can I trace the libuv systemcall call?

Tags: node.js, libuv

I want to check which libuv systemcall is used when I trace a js file.
However, libuv does not seem to be a trace because it comes in a static library form on the node.
What should I do in this case?

I tried to recompile the node for the Node.js and USDT trace, but I could not proceed with a make error.
And ltrace did not check the libuv systemcall.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Trying to do the same, but without bpf?